# How to set scenario in Join Query object in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

How to set scenario in object created from Join Query in Yii2

My query is

```
$model = Answers::find()
            ->joinWith('question')
            ->where(['request_id' => $Request->id])->all();
```

I am getting data in model object. Now when i try to set scenario to this object

```
$model->scenario = 'get_answer';
```

it is giving error "PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

Attempt to assign property of non-object"

How to set scenario to this object.

Comment: Probably `Answers::find()...->all()` returns array of Answers. And after this action your `$model` is array;

And yes, you cant assign property to array.
Explain us please what do you want with this answers.

Comment: @BukharovSergey Yes i am getting array of object in $model variable. Now i want to assign scenario 'get_answer' to these objects

Answer (score 0):

`Answers::find()...->all()` returns `array` of Answers. And after this action your $model is array;

And yes, you cant assign property to array. Explain us please what do you want with this answers.

Your code must be like this:

```
$answers = Answers::find()
        ->joinWith('question')
        ->where(['request_id' => $Request->id])->all();

foreach ($answers as $answer) {
   $answer->scenario = 'get_answer';
}
```